# VBA: Adding Values Within A Multi-Dimensional Array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, sum

I'm stumped and will try to explain this as best as I can.  I'm using one sheet as a database and the other for generating a report.  When the user enters a begin date (20130801) and end date (20130808), the Report workbook will call upon the Database workbook.  Column "A" of the Database workbook is used for labeling and is setup like this:

```
Date  
Dept1  
060000  
...... 'Every 15 min from 6am to 7pm (53 15min time intervals)  
190000   
Dept2  
060000  
...... 'Every 15 min from 6am to 7pm (53 15min time intervals)  
190000  
Dept3 ... 'For a total of 5 dept.
```

I can use .Find to find the first column based on the user's requested begin date and then a Do While loop to cycle through each column until Date (Row 1, Column ?) = end date, but I need help finding a way to add the data under each column to an array and then preserve and add additional data to the array when cycling through the Do While loop.  When done with the Do While loop, I'll take the total values and paste them in a report.  Here is an example:

```
Date.....20130801...20130802...And So On   
Dept1...."Blank"...."Blank"...  
060000...5..........1.........    
061500...6..........2.........      
063000...7..........3.........
```

...

Using Dept1(060000) as an example, I need the array to add each value for each day at this time until the end date is reached.  I'll later need to extract that sum, divide by the number of days, and add the value to a cell on the report.  Any help would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: Hi, I'm not really clear but, first of all, you need to have separate columns for Date, time and Dept.  If you structure your data like this then you can probably achieve your aim with worksheet functions and not require any code.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  Thanks Cool Blue for the suggestion.

```
Sub WorkArrivalHistoryGraph()
'
' WorkArrivalHistoryGraphRetrDataWIPS
'

Dim colBegin As Variant
Dim colEnd As Variant
Dim r As Variant
Dim x As Variant
Dim index As Integer
Dim BeginDate As Variant
Dim EndDate As Variant
Dim ColCount As Integer
Dim wsReport As Worksheet
Dim wsData As Worksheet
Dim wkbkReport As Workbook
Dim wkbkData As Workbook
Dim FindColumn1 As Range
Dim FindColumn2 As Range

Dim ar1(52) As Double
Dim ar2(52) As Variant
Dim ar3(52) As Variant
Dim ar4(52) As Variant
Dim ar5(52) As Variant
Dim ar6(52) As Variant

Set wkbkReport = Workbooks("?.xlsm")
Set wkbkData = Workbooks("?.xlsm")

Set wsReport = wkbkReport.Worksheets("WAHistory")
Set wsData = wkbkData.Worksheets("WorkArrival")

BeginDate = wsReport.Range("B1").Value
EndDate = wsReport.Range("B2").Value

With wkbkData.Sheets("WorkArrival")
Set FindColumn1 = wsData.UsedRange.Find(What:=BeginDate, LookIn:=xlValues)
End With

colBegin = FindColumn1.Column 'this is the first column where you want to check for data

With wkbkData.Sheets("WorkArrival")
Set FindColumn2 = wsData.UsedRange.Find(What:=EndDate, LookIn:=xlValues)
End With

colEnd = FindColumn2.Column 

x = colBegin
ColCount = 0

Do While (wsData.Cells(1, x).Value >= BeginDate And wsData.Cells(1, x).Value <= EndDate)
'This will loop until row 1 is empty
x = x + 1
ColCount = ColCount + 1
Loop

wkbkData.Activate
Sheets("WorkArrival").Select

'Retrieve Data
index = 0
For r = 3 To 55
ar1(index) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(wsData.Range(Cells(r, colBegin), Cells(r, colEnd)))
index = index + 1
Next

index = 0
For r = 57 To 109
ar2(index) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(wsData.Range(Cells(r, colBegin), Cells(r, colEnd)))
index = index + 1
Next

index = 0
For r = 111 To 163
ar3(index) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(wsData.Range(Cells(r, colBegin), Cells(r, colEnd)))
index = index + 1
Next

index = 0
For r = 165 To 217
ar4(index) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(wsData.Range(Cells(r, colBegin), Cells(r, colEnd)))
index = index + 1
Next

index = 0
For r = 219 To 271
ar5(index) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(wsData.Range(Cells(r, colBegin), Cells(r, colEnd)))
index = index + 1
Next

index = 0
For r = 273 To 325
ar6(index) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(wsData.Range(Cells(r, colBegin), Cells(r, colEnd)))
index = index + 1
Next

'Update Report
wkbkReport.Activate
Sheets("WAHistory").Select

index = 0
For r = 4 To 56
    Range("C" & r) = ar1(index)
    Range("D" & r) = ar2(index)
    Range("E" & r) = ar3(index)
    Range("F" & r) = ar4(index)
    Range("G" & r) = ar5(index)
    Range("H" & r) = ar6(index)
    index = index + 1
Next

End Sub
```